# For some reason my animation isn't playing when I want it to when I ask it to through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to have an animation play when I use my axe however it doesn't play even though I coded it to do so. I know that OnTrggerStay works because in the other script that I use for damaging the zombie it is triggered however it still doesn't animate. This script is attached to my axe.

(I am a noob so sorry if code is bad/messy)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

public class Axe_animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimationClip axeAttack;
    public AnimationClip retractBlade;
    private Animation anim;
    private bool hasAnimPlayed = false;
    private Coroutine animat = null;


    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Zombie" && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (animat == null)
            {
                animat = StartCoroutine(Arnim());
            }

        }
    }

    IEnumerator Arnim()
    {
        anim.Play(axeAttack.name);
        hasAnimPlayed = true;

        if (hasAnimPlayed == true)
        {
            anim.Play(retractBlade.name);
            hasAnimPlayed = false;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        animat = null;
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is you are playing the axeAttack animation and then immediately play the retractBlade animation. I would look into [animation states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVCsg_62xYw&ab_channel=Blackthornprod). Instead of calling the animation all from code, call the first state of the axeAttack, then transition out of the state into retractBlade in the animator, not in code. The other option is doing this:

```
IEnumerator Arnim()
{
        anim.Play(axeAttack.name);
        hasAnimPlayed = true;

        // need to wait until the next frame for the animator to catch up
        yield return null;

        // wait for the duration of the current animation
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);

        if (hasAnimPlayed == true)
        {
            anim.Play(retractBlade.name);
            hasAnimPlayed = false;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        animat = null;
}
```

You need to wait for your animation to finish before calling another animation.